# Process the file by replacing some of the delimiters and filtering the data within

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to process a huge file and need to modify the structure if the data. My file has 117 columns but to put it simple, Lets assume that I have a file with 10 columns
Example file:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

I now want to 
- include the column name from col6 through col10 with the column values
- and replace the delimiter with '|' from col6 through col10 for the entire file

required output

```
1,2,3,4,5,col6:6|col7:7|col8:8|col9:9|col10:10
```

Is this a possibility? I'm completely new to regex/ awk. Can some one help please

P.S: Once the data is processed, I'm trying to flush out the zeros from the '|' separated columns...

```
So, if the data is 1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,0,10
I would convert it to 1,2,3,4,5,col6:6|col7:0|col8:8|col9:0|col10:10
and then remove the zero's 1,2,3,4,5,col6:6|col8:8|col10:10

so input: 1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,0,10
Desired output: 1,2,3,4,5,col6:6|col8:8|col10:10
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to do this? Generally it's easier to parse a CSV file than a half CSV, half pipe-and-colon-delimited file.

Comment: I agree with @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. This sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : I need this as part of processing my data. I am trying to load the data in the csv file where some of the columns are stored in to a map. rather than complicating it in further steps, I am trying to make the data compatible with the data format I would be working on and then start the data processing

Comment: @Anil Could you [edit] your question to show an example of what you mean by "some of the columns are stored in to a map."? We might be able to suggest a better approach if we can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: `replace the delimiter with '|' for the entire file` description doesn't match the required output.

Comment: @karafka : Thanks for the catch. updated the question accordingly !

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I have provided the input and desired output to avoid any confusion in my question.

Comment: So in your example, are you just trying to remove any columns between column 6 and column 10 that are zero?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: yes... to some extent. i am removing the zero's that are in col6 - col10 and also, I need to make sure that the data is modified from col6 - col10 as follows:
- each column value would have column name : before the value
- each column after column 6 would be separated by '|'. I have clearly provided the examples in my question posted.

Comment: @Anil Sorry, I may have been unclear. I'm was asking what you're actually trying to do, not how you're trying to do it. I already know how you're trying to do it (adding pipes and colons to your CSV); what I still don't know is what problem you're trying to solve by doing that. Whether you explain the actual problem is up to you, of course, but you'll usually get better answers if you do.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: thanks for the comment. I'm trying to load the data from the csv file in to a framework where half of the columns are stored in to a map as key-value pairs. As 0's are redundant in my case, I have to get rid of them eventually. so trying to get rid of the zero's in the raw file to be processed and loading the data in to the framework. Hope this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F ', *' 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) hdr[i]=$i; next}
  {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", ((i>5)?hdr[i] ":":"") $i,
      ((i<NF)? ((i>5)?"|":",") : ORS)}' file
```

**Output:**

```
1,2,3,4,5,col6:6|col7:7|col8:8|col9:9|col10:10
```

`hdr` is the associative array to hold header column names when `NR==1`

---

**Update:** As per comments OP want to skip columns with zero value. You can use: As per comments OP want to skip columns with zero value. You can use:

```
awk -F ', *' 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) hdr[i]=$i; next}
   {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i>0) printf "%s%s", ((i>5)?hdr[i] ":":"") $i,
            ((i<NF)? ((i>5)?"|":",") : ORS)}' file
```

Comment: Faster than me and a nice solution :)

Comment: Thank you @anubhava ! That works !
Is there a way i could discard the zero values?
I mean if the column is 
1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8,0,10
Can I get 1,2,3,4,5,col6:6|col8:8|col10:10 or should this post go out  as a different question? ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this command worked for me on OSX (BSD awk) also.

Comment: @hek2mgl: It worked for me with both awk and gawk.
Can you also please help me filtering the data (filtering the zero's from the data withing the pipes)

Comment: @Anil: Check updated command for skipping zero value columns.

Comment: Thank you so much @anubhava

Comment: @anubhava: Thank you so much for all the help you've been rendering me. I've used this command. this looks good if the last column is a nonzero. If the last column is zero, the next line starts from the same after the pipe|. Can we do some thing to fix this? -

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '1 {h
        s/\([^,]*,\)\{5\}\(\([^,]*,\)\{4\}[^,]*\).*/\2/
        s/,/|/g
        x
        b
       }
   G
   s/\(\([^,]*,\)\{5\}\)\([^,]*,\)\{4\}[^,]*\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\5\4/
   ' YourFile
```

Posix sed version:

- assuming there is no `,` in field value
- adapt the index

  - 5 to field starting - 1 (6 in this sample)
  - 4 to number of field to catch [ last index - start index ] ( 10 - 6 = 4 in this sample)
  - need modification if field catching start at 1 (`\{0\}` could give unexpected behaviour depending sed version)

Principle:

- take sub field from line 1, change the separator and put it in holding buffer then print original header
- for all other line, add holded value to the line, replace the sub field info by info after the new line (so the added value), print the result